# CSS animation and animation on :hover

Tags: css

I want to have the beginning animation on load and then on :hover to add another animation. The problem is, after I leave the element(not hovering) it goes back to its first animation and repeats it.

Is there any way to avoid this from happening?

Problem video : 
https://youtu.be/uCZdo4FsCj8

Code :

```
    .char {
    animation: slide-down 2s forwards cubic-bezier(0, 1.18, .82, 1.02);
    animation-delay: calc(0s + (0.1s * var(--char-index)));
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    opacity: 1;


    @keyframes slide-down {
        from {
            transform: translate(-125%, 125%);
            opacity: 1;
        }

        to {
            transform: translate(0%);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    &:hover {
        animation: newAnim 0.4s forwards linear;
        color: red;


        @keyframes newAnim {
            from {
                transform: scale(1);
            }

            to {
                transform: scale(1.2);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it without using JavaScript. When `:hover` happens, the `animation-iteration-count` gets reset. This in turn causes the first animation to repeat after letting go of hovering. So you will have to use some JavaScript to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. Do you have any idea on how to do it using JavaScript?

Comment: You’re welcome. Unfortunately, no, I’m not very proficient in JS. If you try your hardest to find it anywhere on google, attempt it, then ask again/edit this question someone who knows JS could help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the animation just for the initial movement, and transitions for the `:hover` effect? This way, the `animation-iteration-count` is not reset after unhovering. Essentially add the following css code:

```
.char {
  ...your animations for initial loading

  transition: color 0.4s linear, transform 0.4s linear;
}


.char:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2); 
  color: red;
}
```

An example of such solution can be found in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqxYPp).